# How can I restrict the rendering of a parented object without removing the parent-child relationship?

Tags: parent, outliner

**For Example:** I have a cube and a sphere in my scene. The cube and the sphere have a parent-child relationship, such that the cube is a child of the sphere; as illustrated:

[image: Image Shows Parent-Child Relationship of Sphere & a Cube]

The **Outliner** only shows the properties of the sphere. How can I restrict the cube from the render without removing the parent-child relationship?

Comment: @Nazgûl My question is, how to restrict the render of cube without removing Parent-Child relationship? Infact, with restrict I mean It doesn't appear in the render. It has nothing to do with animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Outliner is designed to be able to display a 'heirarchy' of information, that is, data that belongs to other data, including parent/child relationships.

To expand the Outliner heirarchy press the '+' (which changes to a '-' when clicked) next to the parent object:

[image]

You now have access to the selection, render and viewport visibility properties of the child object.

You can also press <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> to expand or collapse levels of the Outliner (while the cursor is in the Outliner) for multiple objects.

See the *Outliner* page in the Blender Manual for more information:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html

Comment: Worth noting the somewhat unfortunate shortcut is `Ctrl + H` and to unrestrict is `Ctrl + Alt + H`

Comment: Unfortunate? Hide, unhide. (: